# Button show/hide Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a service and view in AngularJS that provides dynamic buttons based on the control. I can't get it to achieve hiding/showing of the buttons from variables in my controller.

HeaderRemote.js

```
app.factory('HeaderRemote',['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var factory = {            
        toolbar: []
    };

    // on history changes, remove toolbar
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        factory.toolbar.splice(0,factory.toolbar.length);
    });

    return factory;
}]);
```

HeaderController.js

```
return app.controller('HeaderCtrl',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'HeaderRemote', function ($rootScope, $scope, HeaderRemote{

        $scope.toolbar = HeaderRemote.toolbar;
}]);
```

HeaderView.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-repeat="tool in toolbar">
        <button type="button" 
                class="btn btn-link" 
                ng-click="tool.fn()" 
                ng-show="tool.show === undefined || tool.show">
                    <span ng-show="tool.icon" class="{{tool.icon}}"></span>
                    <span>{{tool.name}}</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then my other controller manipulate the header remote like:

```
HeaderRemote.toolbar.push({
   name: "Save",
   fn: $scope.save,
   icon: "icon-check-alt",
   show: $scope.showSave
});
```

`$scope.showSave` is initially set to `false` but later I set it to `true` and it never changes in the header.

Comment: where is the code that set it to false?

Comment: its set to false on load and then when form is 'dirty' its marked true

Comment: To be honest it looks a bit odd what you are trying to achieve but have you tried: $scope.$apply(function(){/*something*/});

Comment: @Dalorzo do you have better feedback for a alternative way?  I need the header decoupled from other controls.

Comment: If I were you would build a directive for toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initially push the new item into HeaderRemote.toolbar:

```
HeaderRemote.toolbar.push({
   name: "Save",
   fn: $scope.save,
   icon: "icon-check-alt",
   show: $scope.showSave
});
```

You are assigning whatever the current value of $scope.showSave is. However, you are not binding that new array element to $scope, so if $scope changes, that will not change the array inside of HeaderRemote. If you want, you can set up a watcher inside the controller which calls HeaderRemote.toolbar.push(), like so:

```
$scope.$watch("showSave", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        /** Note that you'll need some way of retaining the index of the Header item you want to change. **/
        HeaderRemote.toolbar[0].show = newValue;
    }
})
```